# What's the difference between X.509 and PKCS#7 Certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates, x.509

1. Am I correct calling file with .p7b file extension saved as 'Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard - PKCS#7 Certificates (.P7B)' in Windows - a 'PKCS#7 certificate'? Or is it better called 'X.509 certificate saved in PKCS#7 format'?
2. When would one choose one certificate format over another? Do these formats have any particular strengths or weaknesses?
3. Adding this question after my first two edits. How is PKCS#7 format different compared to DER/PEM file formats?

Thanks

---

Edit #1: Firefox under Linux offers me an ability to export some website's certificate as:

- X.509 Certificate (PEM)
- X.509 Certificate (DER)
- X.509 Certificate (PKCS#7)

Does it mean that PKCS#7 here is just a binary file format similar to but distinct from DER? If true then .p7b file is just an X.509 certificate saved in PKCS#7 format (as opposed to PEM or DER formats).

---

Edit #2: Follow up to my first edit. This page [OpenSSL: Documents, pkcs7](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs7.html) suggests that PKCS#7 can be encrypted in either DER or PEM. From that I deduce that PKCS#7 is not a distinct binary file format. Now I'm totally confused.

---

Edit #3: Ok, I figured the relationship between PEM and DER formats. The Base64 encoded payload of the PEM file is actually data in DER format. So initially the X.509 certificate is encoded in DER format and then optionally you can encode the resulted 'DER encoded certificate' to 'PEM encoded certificate'. I'm still having difficulties fitting PKCS#7 part of the puzzle.

---

Edit #4: Another piece of information. PKCS#7 seems to be a container that allows to bundle together several X.509 certificates prior to encode them into DER format (which is different from PEM format where you can bundle certificates together in the same file by just pasting them one after another).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You've evolved to mostly right, but to add several points
and expand on @CoverosGene' [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/73198) more than I felt comfortable doing in an edit:

**X.509** defines a certificate (and some other things not relevant here) in ASN.1,
a (very!) general data structuring method which has several defined encodings, of which
**DER** Distinguished Encoding Representation is quite common and is used here.

**PEM** format -- for several types of data of which a certificate is only one --
is much as you say just binary (DER) data encoded in base64 **(edit)** broken into lines normally every 64 chars (but there are variations), plus header and trailer lines
consisting of dashes + BEGIN or END + the type of data, in this case CERTIFICATE + dashes.
Those lines look redundant to a human but they are expected and mostly required by software.
PEM (Privacy Enhanced Mail) was actually a complete standard for secure email that has now
been mostly forgotten (see below) *except* for its encoding format.
**(edit)** As of 2015 there is [RFC 7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) describing in detail *most* use of 'PEM' formats for modern crypto data.

**PKCS#7** was defined by RSA (the company, not the algorithm) as a multi-purpose format
for encrypted and/or signed data. It was turned over to IETF and evolved into
**CMS Cryptographic Message Syntax** in [RFC 2630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2630), then [RFC 3369](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3369), then [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852), then [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652),
hence the wording of the Windows (inetopt) prompt. "PKCS#7" is often used to mean **both**
the original RSA PKCS#7 and the IETF successor CMS, in the same way "SSL" is often used for
both the original Netscape protocol and the IETF successor TLS Transport Level Security.

The **.p7b or .p7c** format is a special case of PKCS#7/CMS: a SignedData structure containing
no "content" and zero SignerInfos, but one or more certificates (usually) and/or CRLs (rarely).
Way back when this provided a standard way to handle **(edit)** the set of certificates needed to make up a **chain** (not necessarily in order).

PKCS#7/CMS is (are?) also ASN.1 and depending on circumstances can be either DER or **BER**,
a closely-related encoding with some very minor differences that most DER decoders handle.

While PKCS#7/CMS like any DER or BER object *can* be PEM-formatted, <strike>I've not seen any implementation other than
openssl</strike> **(edit)** it is rare for certs. (Java `CertificateFactory` can read PKCS7/CMS-certs-only from DER or PEM, but `CertPath.getEncoded` writes it only to DER.) In contrast both DER and PEM formats for a single cert are common.

PKCS#7/CMS is also used as the basis for **S/MIME** secure email (multiple rfcs starting from 5751).
Basically PEM encoded PKCS#7 into ASCII text which email systems of the 1980s could easily handle, while
S/MIME represents CMS as MIME entities which are encoded in *several* ways modern email systems can handle.

**OpenSSL** confused matters by implementing, in order: a **pkcs7** command which handles
the certs-CRLs-only case not full PKCS#7; a **crl2pkcs7** command which actually handles
CRLs and certs, but again not the rest of PKCS#7; a **smime** command which actually handles both S/MIME
and PKCS#7/CMS for most cases of encrypted and/or signed messages; and a **cms** command which actually handles
both S/MIME and PKCS#7/CMS for a more complete set of cases.

So I would describe the options as: a cert in PEM or DER format; a (single) cert
in a PKCS#7 container or for short just p7, and mention PEM only in the rare case it applies;
or a *cert chain* in PKCS#7 or p7. The semantic difference between a single cert and a cert chain
is at least as important as the format difference between a cert by itself or in a container.

And this doesn't even reach the widespread confusion between a certificate by itself (for some other entity, most often a CA root or anchor) and the combination of privatekey PLUS certificate -- or usually chain -- that you use to prove your own identity, for example as an SSL/TLS server or when signing S/MIME email. *That* uses the originally-Microsoft PFX Personal Information Exchange format, or its standardized form PKCS#12 or "p12".

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that a PKCS#7/CMS `SignedData` structure used as a mere bag for certificates is _unordered_: you can put several certificates, but the format does not keep track of any ordering. Therefore, it can transport a certificate chain exactly as well as IKEA sells furniture. Decoders must still work out who signed who in the chain.

Comment: @Thomas good point, edited. And the same for `SignedData` that *does* convey a signature (or several), but that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: for the .p7c the Windows Explorer shows a file type "Certificate" but for the .p7b it shows   "CertificateS PKCS #7". So as far I understood the .p7c is only one cert while the .p7b is a full chain. Could you clarify on this? Do you know any program that generates the .p7c?

Comment: BTW is any specification for the file extensions?

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev (sorry for delay, I couldn't refind you in my overfull pending box): in general only Microsoft cares about file extensions. I know many programs that create or read (or both) the PKCS7-certs-only _format_ (and have written some myself) but they can use any extension the user chooses; p7b and p7c are only conventions and (often) defaults. FWIW p7c -- but not p7b -- is published in the SMIME RFCs (2633, 3851, 5751, now 8551).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you. The Kleopatra program uses p7s for signatures (both attached and detached) and the p7m for encrypted. They also are registered in the share-mime-info so all Linux distros knows this extensions and shows an icon for them. Windows and macOS also know them. I wasn't able to find a program that generates p7c but it should contains a cert only while p7b chain of certificates. I added them to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev If I had to guess why Windows shows a different description for `.p7c` vs `.p7b`, the _**c**_ would stand for _certificate_, meaning one certificate, while _**b**_ would stand for _bundle_ (or as Windows shows, `Certificates PKCS #7`), or multiple certificates are contained therein. However, if you were to rename the `.p7b` file to `.p7c`, or vice versa, it would still be valid--as it's still a PKCS #7-formatted file.

Answer (score 13):

PKCS #7 can be thought of as a format that allows multiple certificates to be bundled together, either DER- or PEM- encoded, and may include certificates and certificate revocation lists (CRLs).

Per [RFC2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315), PKCS#7 is

```
a general syntax for data that may have
cryptography applied to it, such as digital signatures and digital
envelopes. The syntax admits recursion, so that, for example, one
envelope can be nested inside another, or one party can sign some
previously enveloped digital data.
```